# AndroidでMaterial Designのボタンの背景色を変えたい

Tags: android, material-design

Androidでボタンの背景色を変えたく、以下のように設定しました。

```
<Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:text="Button" />
```

ですが画像のように角ばった形になります。
元の形のままで背景色を変更するにはどうすればいいですか？

[image: 普通のボタン]
[image: 角ばったボタン]

Answer (score 1):

`styles.xml`での`theme`カスタマイズで、

```
<item name="android:colorButtonNormal">@color/colorPrimary</item>
```

です（Lollipop 未満では`android：`を取って `"colorButtonNormal"`）。

背景色指定だと、ボタンもボタンの背景も両方とも色が変わってしまうので、そのようになります。形が変わったのではなく、背景に溶け込んでしまっているだけです。

Comment: それではすべてのボタンが変わってしまいませんか？
それぞれに違う色を割り振ったりできないのでしょうか

Comment: ボタンのDrawable画像自体を定義すれば可能のようですが（[参考](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1006843/An-Efficient-Way-to-Make-Button-Color-Change-on-An)）、ボタン毎に色を変えるというのは、既に Material Design の指針から外れている方向性だと思いますが……

Comment: なるほど、知りませんでした...

Comment: [Style > Color](https://www.google.com/design/spec/style/color.html) にありますが、Primary color をベースに、同系色の Secondary color を選び、それらに対してコントラストの高い Accent color を選び、「色にも意味を持たせる」というのが Material Design の狙いです。無意味に色を色々と使ってしまうと、 Accent color が機能しなくなってしまいます。

Answer (score 1):

ボタンごとに異なるテーマを設定することで、任意のボタンの色だけ変更することが可能です。
例えばstyles.xmlで以下のように指定したとします。

```
<style name="Button1">
    <item name="android:colorButtonNormal">#FF0000</item>
</style>

<style name="Button2">
    <item name="android:colorButtonNormal">#00FF00</item>
</style>
```

layout.xmlで色を変更したいボタンに、作成したスタイルをthemeとして指定すれば、そのボタンだけ色が変わります。

```
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:text="button1"
        android:theme="@style/Button1"
        />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:text="button2"
        android:theme="@style/Button2"
        />
```